# Passing copies of a function to lambda expressions in C++

Tags: multithreading, lambda, concurrency, pass-by-reference, function-pointers

```
class Foo{ 
    int function(int* &var){ //do stuff
    };
}foo;

int* A;
int* B;

add2Thread_1(std::function<void()> &func);
add2Thread_1(std::function<void()> &func);

int main(){
add2Thread_1([&](){/*other stuff*/ foo.function(A)});
add2Thread_2([&](){/*other stuff*/ foo.function(B)});
}
```

I am working on a multi-threaded program that calls the same function from different threads. I add the functions to different threads by utilizing lambda expressions that captures the values by reference. `Add2Thread` functions calls the functions by reference as well.

My question is if the `foo.function(&var)` called by the different threads are the same instance of the function, or just a copy of the same function. In my experience so far, it seems like the secondary is true, because in some cases `Thread_1` delivers the value `*B` and the function `foo.function` is the only place where they can mix up.

If it is so, is there way for me to call only the foo.function by copy in the lambda expression, or any other workaround for that matter?
When I try to do
`add2Thread_1([&,std::function<int(int*)>](){/*other stuff*/ foo.function(A)});` the compiler gives an error.

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: `foo.function()` isn't a function; it's a method. A method is implemented behind the scenes by a C function that takes a pointer to the instance, and the rest of the arguments. C functions don't have any state and there is no semantic difference between a "copy" and the original. It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: The problem is when the method `foo.function(A)` is called  by the `Thread_1` right after the `Thread_2` called the method  `foo.function(B)` within a short time frame, somehow the values get mixed up and the `Thread_1` forwards the value `*B`. But this is rather perplexing to me, because these two threads are never exposed to each others variables outside this method. My suspicion was when the same method is called by different threads the same instance of instructions of the method including the pointers to the arguments, the pointer to the argument is overwritten by the other thread.

Comment: Although It doesn't make any semantic difference, I was trying to solve the problem by giving each thread the same set of instructions on different parts of the memory, and thus circumvent the argument pointer overwrite problem.

Comment: You need to show the code of these `add2Thread_1()` functions and what the output is, because it's impossible to know what you're describing.